# How get all vm's details from multiple vcenter?

Tags: python, vmware

Looking suggestions, My requirement is to get all vm's details including server information list no.of disks size, vcenter, ESXi cluster, Datacenter, Vmfolder etc.. and display information like below

1. ABC Linux datacenter1 vcenter1 /os/linux_folder etc..
2. xyz Windows Datacenter2 vcenter2 /os/windows_folder etc..

Is that possible with python?

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible using python sdk. I leave a link to Vmware SDK. https://code.vmware.com/web/sdk/7.0/vsphere-automation-python

Get all VMs example
https://code.vmware.com/samples/567/get-all-vms